# SOAP API Integration

Tags: soap-api, integration

I am new for SOAP API integration could you please suggest me where is the exact example for do this step by step complete example

Comment: you can call Soap api from almost all modern programming languages like  Java, .Net, PHP or even Apex. So for which language you need example for ? Please take some time to add details to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through following links-

[SOAP API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_steps_walk_through_code.htm)

http://sriramp84.blogspot.in/2012/10/salesforceapex-callout-to-external.html
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AxK9IAK